# A group "generated" by some subgroups

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition

Consider a group $G$, and $G_1,...,G_K$ are subgroups of $G$. Also, $G_i\bigcap G_j=\{ e\}$ holds for all $i \ne j$.

And for all $g\in G$, $g$ can be expressed as $g=g_{k_1}\circ...\circ g_{k_K}$, where $k_1,...,k_K$ is a permutation of $1,...,K$, and $g_{k_i} \in G_{k_i}$ for all $i=1,...,K$.

Intuitively, we can say the group $G$ is "generated" by subgroups $G_1,...,G_K$.

Does group theory have a similar concept of this "generation" ? I know the concept of [Generating set of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group), but it's still a bit different from what I describe above.

Comment: Possibly $G$ can be a [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) of the subgroups, though I don't think your conditions _quite_ guarantee that the subgroups fit together as a semidirect product ...

Comment: If you can take $k_1,\ldots,k_K$ to be the _same_ permutation for every $g$, then you have a [Zappa–Szép product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product).

Comment: @Troposphere The semidirect product is not symmetric in the factors, but this concept a priori is

Comment: @Troposphere It seems that the Zappa–Szép product is the most similar concept to what the question describes.

Comment: Certainly, $G=\langle G_1,\ldots G_n\rangle$; it is *literally* generated by these subgroups. Not sure what else you want.